# How to solve this with network flow or any other solutions?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, bipartite, network-flow

There are providers P1 to Pm, who have A1 to Am apples respectively. And users U1 to Un, who need D1 to Dn apples respectively.

Every provider has connections to certain users(some of them, not all).  Users can get apples from different providers.

The question is in which way, we can satisfy most users?

Sorry for the unclear description. There is only one kind of resource and one user can only have one requirement.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What kind of demand and supply nodes you are talking about?

Comment: how should we understand this - does provider Pi have only the resource Ri? And similarly for the Users and the requirements: can a user have multiple requirements? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry for the bad description. There is only one kind resource. A1 to Am are the amount that P1 to Pm have. D1 to Dn are the amount that U1 to Un need. And a user can have only one requirement.

Comment: If two users require 2 each from a resource Ri. And the provider Pi has exactly 2 of those, should he rather give one to each user or is it better to give 2 to one user and 0 to the other?

Comment: The question is to satisfy most users. If he give one to each, he satisfy 0.  So it is better to give 2 to one. And there is only one kind of resource. A1, Am and D1, Dn are meant to represent the quantities.   Sorry for my poor english.